# Get approval status in edit form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, form, content-approval

Is there an easy way to retrieve item approval status (moderationStatus) inside the edit form? During display of edit form I need to know wheather the currently edited item was approved or not. I see that the information is not reflected in a hidden column or else. I have the following ideas:

- Custom flag column that indicates if the item was approved.
- Get the current item via js rest call and check OData__ModerationStatus.

I just want to know if there is an easier way to get the moderationStatus of the item I am editing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Content Approval status is stored in List Item (`_ModerationStatus`) I would recommend to leverage any client APIs (JSOM, REST or SOAP) for that purpose.

### How to retrieve content approval status using client APIs

**JSOM**

```
function getListItemModerationInfo(listId,itemId,success,error)
{
   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = ctx.get_web();
   var list = web.get_lists().getById(listId);
   var item = list.getItemById(itemId);
   ctx.load(item);

   ctx.executeQueryAsync(
      function() {
          var moderationInfo = {};  
          moderationInfo.Status = item.get_item('_ModerationStatus');
          moderationInfo.Comments = item.get_item('_ModerationComments');
          success(moderationInfo); 
      },
      error);
}
```

Usage: how to retrieve content approval status of list item in edit form

```
var listId = _spPageContextInfo.pageListId; //current List Id
var itemId = parseInt(GetUrlKeyValue('ID')); //current Item Id

getListItemModerationInfo(listId,itemId, 
   function(info){
       console.log(info.Status);
   },
   function(sendera,args){
       console.log(args.get_message());
   });
```

**REST**

Endpoint: `/_api/web/lists/getById('<guid>')/items(<id>)?$expand=FieldValuesAsHtml`

```
function getListItemDetails(webUrl,listId,itemId)
{
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getById('" + listId + "')/items(" + itemId + ")?$expand=FieldValuesAsHtml";
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        headers: {
           "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
    });
}
```

Usage

```
var listId = _spPageContextInfo.pageListId;
var itemId = parseInt(GetUrlKeyValue('ID'));
getListItemDetails(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,listId,itemId)
.done(function(data)
{
    var moderationStatusName = data.d.FieldValuesAsHtml['OData__x005f_ModerationStatus'];
    console.log(moderationStatusName);
})
.fail(function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

Comment: Probably the best solution and the correct one :) But couldn't you check the property of WPQ2FormCtx.ListData._UIVersionString , where approved would be 1.0, 2.0 etc?

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. This is a full featured answer! I've also used a REST call to get the modStat to get this information. So your answer tells me I'm not doing wrong.

Comment: Great, glad it helped you :)

Comment: Anders, thanks! That's an interesting idea to utilize that property, will check it also..